# Reading from STDIN and using data immediatly (while still reading) or opening a URL with zbar

Tags: bash, command-line

I need to read lines from STDIN and process them. I could do something like:

```
<print lines to STDOUT> | while read line; do
   <process $line>
done
```

But this means that *first* all lines are printed and piped and *then* they are processed. I want to process every single line immediately, eventually before the next lines are sent to STDOUT.

This might be useful if the lines should be processed while they are are generated (e.g. a log file). My task is to use [zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) (warning! the web page crashes Firefox...) to scan several QR codes and to open its URLs in Firefox.
If run `zbarcam --raw` the webcam is used to scan QR codes. If a QR code is found the URL is printed to STDOUT immediately, but zbarcam does not terminate. So I'd like to read this line and to run `firefox $url` or so (but without waiting for other URLs).

I've found [a solution](http://blog.michiwend.com/2011/05/06/die-zbar-tastatur/), but I'm wondering if this can't be done easier. Basically he writes the output of `zbarcam` to a temporary file and waits until something is written there:

```
zbarcam --raw > tmpfile &
...
while [[ ! -s $tmp ]] ; do
  sleep 1
done
```

Can this be done with out temporary files and without a loop with `sleep 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt does work:

```
tail -f temp.file | while read LINE; do firefox $LINE; done
```

Then in another terminal, append to the temp file so that tail -f prints a line to STDOUT:

```
echo 'google.com' >> temp.file
```

Every time you do this, firefox will open a new tab.

Comment: Well, that's really strange. I was fighting like 2 or 3 hours with this problem. And now it simply works as expected... :)  One hint for others: A firefox process should be running already!

Comment: Since you say `zbar --raw` does not terminate, this sounds like everything you wanted. Is that so? Anyway, it's best to also quote `$LINE`, so urls with ampersands don't break the loop.

Answer (score 2):

After trying around a bit more, I've found a partial solution:

```
zbarcam --raw|xargs -L1 firefox
```

The crucial part is the parameter `-L1`, which tells `xargs` to read only one single line. After reading the first QR code it runs firefox. `zbar`  then still runs, but I can't scan a second QR code (`xargs` has to be called a second time somehow).

Answer (score 0):

very, very close:

```
zbarcam --raw | xargs -n 1 chromium-browser
```

This works beautifully for me, every scan ends up in a new tab.